# Date value mismatch between REST Server and Postman

Tags: spring, rest, date, spring-restcontroller

I am developing a REST server using spring framework.

I am returning a list of Model object(Employee which containing a Date field

So my Model class looks like:

```
Class Employee {
 private String empId;
 private Date joinDate;
}
```

My controller method looks like:

```
@GetMapping("/Employee")
    public List<EmployeeLeaves> searchEmployeeLeaveDetails(@RequestParam(value = "filter", required = false) String filter) throws Exception {

        List<Employee> empList = service.searchEmployee(filter);

        return empList;
    }
```

When I tried to call this api from postman in response it always shows joinDate is 1 day less than actual date.

I debugged this issue and found that in  controller the date is value is correct

**Below are the test/debug results**

```
Value for joinDate(Column type is Date) in Database: '2018-10-27'
Value for joinDate(java.sql.timestamp) in Controller: 2018-10-27 00:00:00.0
Value retried in postman's JSON response : "2018-10-26T18:30:00.000+0000"
```

Anyone have idea why postman response shows date as 26 instead of 27?
Any timezone related factor came in between?

Answer (score 1):

You should **avoid** using [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html), as it's a *legacy class* now. Java 8 introduced a [new API for dates, times, instants and durations](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/package-summary.html) based on the ISO calendar system.

The closest equivalent to [`Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Date.html) is [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Instant.html) which represents a timestamp, a moment on the timeline in UTC. But you probably want to use [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) instead, as it stores all date and time fields as well as the offset from UTC/Greenwich.

Quoting the [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) class documentation:

> It is intended that `ZonedDateTime` or `Instant` is used to model data in simpler applications. This class [`OffsetDateTime`] may be used when modeling date-time concepts in more detail, or when communicating to a database or in a network protocol.